# OOP Javascript callback method on Google Data API

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to make my calendar events reader in javascript OOP. On the `checkAuth()` function, when calling `handleAuthResult` followings are observed.

1. When using `this.handleAuthResult` , the variable `this.config.myvar` inside the method `handleAuthResult()` becomes undefined.
2. When using `this.handleAuthResult()` , the variable `authResult` inside the method `handleAuthResult()` becomes undefined.

the code:

```
var config = new Config();
var Manager = new Manager(config);

Manager.checkAuth();

function Config(){
    this.myvar = "this is what i want";
    this.clientId="client id";
    this.scopes="scopes";
}

function Manager(theConfig){
    this.config = theConfig;
}

Manager.prototype = {
    constructor: Manager,

handleAuthResult : function (authResult) {
        console.log(authResult);
        console.log(this.config.myvar);
},

checkAuth : function () {
        console.log("checkAuth()");
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: this.config.clientId, scope:    this.config.scopes, immediate: true}, this.handleAuthResult);
    }
}
```

I need to use both `this.config.myvar` and `authResult` on call back of the `handleAuthResult()`.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the @zerkms's comment I was able to resolved the issue with `bind` method.

I can pass current instance with the `bind` method which will be referred `this` as `Manager` inside the `handleAuthResult()`.

```
checkAuth : function () {
        console.log("checkAuth()");
        gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: this.config.clientId, scope:    this.config.scopes, immediate: true}, this.handleAuthResult.bind(this));
    }
}
```